# Disable default pagination in Vuetify Data table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working with the Vuetify Data table and it seems like by default, the table sorts everything according to name. How can i Disable that? I am not even using any pagination. I want the data to render in the order it is.

Check out this simple [Codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/oNjyWrv?editors=1010).

Here is a simple working demo:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    selected: [],
    headers: [{
        text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
        align: "left",
        value: "name"
      },
      {
        text: "Calories",
        value: "calories"
      },
      {
        text: "Fat (g)",
        value: "fat"
      }
    ],
    desserts: [{
        name: "Frozen Yogurt",
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0
      },
      {
        name: "Ice cream sandwich",
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0
      },
      {
        name: "Eclair",
        calories: 262,
        fat: 16.0
      }
    ]
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table v-model="selected" :headers="headers" :items="desserts" select-all item-key="name" class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:headers="props">
        <tr>
          <th>
            <v-checkbox :input-value="props.all" :indeterminate="props.indeterminate" primary hide-details></v-checkbox>
          </th>
          <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text">
            <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
            {{ header.text }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <tr :active="props.selected" @click="props.selected = !props.selected">
          <td>
            <v-checkbox :input-value="props.selected" primary hide-details></v-checkbox>
          </td>
          <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
disable-initial-sort
```

Use this property in v-data-table like this

```
<v-data-table disable-initial-sort v-model="selected" :headers="headers" :items="desserts" select-all item-key="name" class="elevation-1">
```

Answer (score 1):

The codepen you added is old, for disable sorting add `disable-initial-sort` to data table tag, for disable pagination add `hide-actions`, here is updated your [codepen](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/BaoVZEV)

In vuetify version 2, for for disable sorting add `disable-sort` to data table tag, for disable pagination add `disable-pagination` or `hide-default-footer`, here is new version [codepen](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/xxwzLxE)